# Where can I predict and follow the exact time of Ethereum Merge event?

Tags: the-merge

I need to book a bar for the event. The bar needs to know at least one day ahead when they are booked for a private event.

Comment: There's quite a few sites like [WenMerge](https://wenmerge.com/) for checking the estimated date which might be of use to you

Answer (score 1):

https://blog.ethereum.org/2022/08/24/mainnet-merge-announcement
mentions:

> Estimates for the transition can be found at bordel.wtf and 797.io/themerge

Answer (score 0):

Google search now directly shows you the Ethereum merge countdown

[image]